# Android Display and hide check boxes on all the rows of recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i have a recyclerview and i need to display check boxes on clicking action bar menu like shown here [image: show check boxes]

and like this to check all and hide all
[image: hide/selectall]

How can i achieve something like this?? I tried to call a adapter method from my activity and set visiblity of checkbox to visible and then calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` but it displays checkbox in only one row.. here is my adapter code

```
public class CartItemListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CartItemListAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<CartItemDetail> cartItemDetailList;
    private Context context;
    private CheckBox checkbox;



    public CartItemListAdapter (List<CartItemDetail> cartItemDetailList){
        this.cartItemDetailList=cartItemDetailList;
    }


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private TextView cartProductName, totalValue,leftValue;
        private ImageView cartProductImage, incrementButton,decrementButton;
        private EditText coinValue;




        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            cartProductImage=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.cart_product_image);
            incrementButton=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.cartIncrementImg);
            decrementButton=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.cartDecrementImg);
            coinValue=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.cartBetCoinValue);
            cartProductName=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.cart_product_name);
            totalValue=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.cart_ProductTotal_qty);
            leftValue=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.cart_ProductRemaining_qty);
            checkbox=(CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.cart_item_checkbox);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }

    }



    @Override
    public CartItemListAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        context=parent.getContext();

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.cart_item_row, parent, false);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                callProductEventDetails();
            }
        });


        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CartItemListAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        CartItemDetail cartItemDetail=cartItemDetailList.get(position);
        holder.cartProductName.setText(cartItemDetail.getCartProductName());
        holder.leftValue.setText(Html.fromHtml("<pre>" + "Left:" + "</pre>" + "<font color=\"#EF4836\">" + cartItemDetail.getProductLeftQty() + "</font>"));
        holder.totalValue.setText("Total:"+cartItemDetail.getProductTotalQty());
        holder.coinValue.setText(cartItemDetail.getAddedCoins());


        Glide.with(context)
                .load(cartItemDetail.getCartProductImageUrl())
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                .fitCenter()
                .into(holder.cartProductImage);
}

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cartItemDetailList.size();
    }

    private void callProductEventDetails(){
        Intent intent= new Intent(context, ProductEventDetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("eventStatus","inProgress");
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void displayCheckBox(){
checkbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

xml for item row..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
    <CheckBox
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:padding="-25dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/cart_item_checkbox"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleX="0.40"
        android:scaleY="0.40"
        android:button="@drawable/cart_checkbox_selector"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/cart_product_image"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cart_product_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#1d1d1d"
        android:text="iPhone7 128G xxxxxxxxxxx xxx"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cart_ProductTotal_qty"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cart_product_name"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Total:750"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/cart_ProductTotal_qty"
            android:id="@+id/cart_ProductRemaining_qty"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:text="Left:95"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_below="@+id/cart_ProductTotal_qty"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/counter_stroke_border">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cartDecrementImg"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/minus_decrement"/>
            <View
                android:layout_width="0.6dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#8d8d8d"></View>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/cartBetCoinValue"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#EF4836"
                android:ellipsize="start"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="1"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
            <View
                android:layout_width="0.6dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#8d8d8d"></View>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cartIncrementImg"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/plus_increment"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: So what is the issue ?

Comment: @Piyush issue is i want to display the check box on every row but currently when i set the visibility of checkbox from a adapter method(called from activity) check box is visible only in one random row.. but i want it to be visible on all the rows

Comment: Just access all checkboxes from adapter using _getCount()_ method.

Comment: Can u pls elaborate on that.. im a kinda beginner in android...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modify your code as follows :

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(...) {
    ...
    ...
    if(//condition for visibility) {
        checkbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        checkbox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Inside the Activity modify the dataset ie., `cartItemDetailList`
and call  `yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: How can he determine which checkbox is set for visibility ?

Comment: That depends on his requirement(business logic). Thus, I have not mentioned any specific condition for visibility.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `bolean isSelected` in your `CartItemDetail` model. And when you want to show hide checkbox set visibility to `VISIBLE` or `Gone` according to your scenario.

You have to put a check in your adapter like `cartItemDetail.isSelected()` is set to `true` then show your checkbox and when it is set to `false` then set visibility to gone.

You can `setSelected()` to `true` or `false` according to your event.

put this check in your adapter.

```
           if(cartItemDetail.isSelected){
            yourCheckBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       }else{
            yourCheckBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply access all your checkboxes through

```
for (int i = 0; i < recyclerView.getChildCount(); i++) {
 View view = recyclerView.getChildAt(i);
 if(view==null){
    return;
 }
 CheckBox checkbox=(CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.cart_item_checkbox);
 checkbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)// same for hide use View.GONE
}
```